# Remove component's view name from url joomla 4

Tags: joomla, joomla4

I am using Joomla 4.2.1.
I installed custom component which is previously used into Joomla 3.10.11.

I create a menu item with view from this component.

On Joomla 3.10.11 it works fine

for example : http://mylocal.local/index.php/kurse-nach-datum

But

on Joomla 4.2.1 it create url with view name

For example : http://mylocal.local/index.php/kurse-nach-datum/courses

`kurse-nach-datum` is the Alias of link

and link is  `index.php?option=com_course&view=courses`

Comment: You might get better attention if you ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks you for your suggestion. I will ask my question on Joomla Stack Exchange.